# Export Datatable to Excel File (.XLSX)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, excel, vba

I use this code to export Datatable to excel file (.xlsx)

```
Dim attachment As String = "attachment; filename=Excel.xlsx"
    Response.ClearContent()
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment)
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    Dim tab As String = ""
    For Each dc As DataColumn In dt.Columns
        Response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName)
        tab = vbTab
    Next
    Response.Write(vbLf)

    Dim i As Integer
    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        tab = ""
        For i = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            Response.Write(tab & dr(i).ToString())
            tab = vbTab
        Next
        Response.Write(vbLf)
    Next
    Response.End()
```

When I download the file I get This message :

"Excel cannot open the file 'Excel.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid "

I use Excel 2010

Any Ideas why ?!

Comment: C# or Vb which one is it. According to code its not C#. Please fix the tags...

Answer (score 1):

Your are creating a TSV - tab separated value.
Instead .xlsx try using .tsv

Answer (score -1):

If you want to export as excel, maybe you can the third-party lib NPOI to make a excel object.